# What are some good books for Apache Ignite?

Tags: ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

can anyone suggest me Apache Ignite Books and PDF for beginner.

Answer (score 5):

How about ["High Performance In-Memory computing with Apache Ignite"](http://www.lulu.com/shop/shamim-bhuiyan-and-michael-zheludkov-and-timur-isachenko/high-performance-in-memory-computing-with-apache-ignite/paperback/product-23136460.html)?

Comment: Rather than this book any other option??

Comment: Yes.Is there any other option?

Comment: There is no other book. Another option would be to go through Ignite documentation and getting started guide.